# What is "GET http://httpheader.net 301" in my nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers

I see something like this in my nodejs app... Am I under hack attack ?

```
GET http://httpheader.net 301 5.464 ms - 108
GET http://www.httpheader.net/ 200 6.820 ms - -
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link from support of httpheader.net [says](http://blogadmin.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/167281-i-m-seeing-get-http-domain-name-http-1-1-404-in-my-weblogs-what-does-this-mean-)

> This is usually an indication that either the IP you are on had a
>   proxy server at one time, your IP is being probed to see if it
>   contains a proxy server or someone just has their software miss
>   configured. These can usually be ignored as they pose no direct
>   threat.

Also the default API routing on your server side is not very well configured. It should be returning `404` if the page was not found on your server instead you are returning 200.

You can block all these requests if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I don't know why it's returning 200 because everything else returning 404 this is why it was weird for me... Do you know what can be wrong in my settings ? Thanks a lot