# httpheader.net as HTTP_HOST

Tags: php, apache

I am using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in my script. but sometimes, instead geting my domain name I get `httpheader.net` as result when my script is online.

note that my server is LAMP.

how this is possible? could be a hack and should I worry about this?

Comment: This is duplicate question. About it you can read here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761532/what-is-get-http-httpheader-net-301-in-my-nodejs-app

Answer (score 0):

I feel `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` may help you as this will retrieve domain name from your conf file.